when bsearch matches first element in array with 2 values it returns nil. Why?
I don't understand why bsearch method returns nil, when array has 2 values.
arr = [1, 2]

arr.bsearch { |el| el < 2 }


bsearch doc
You just need to read the doc for Array#bsearch carefully. It states that are two forms or modes of bsearch: "find-minimum mode and find-any mode. In either case, the elements of the array must be monotone (or sorted) with respect to the block." With find-minimum mode the block returns true or false; with find-any mode a value of the same class as the elements of the array is returned by the block. You are therefore using the find-minimum mode.
Also from the doc, in find-minimum mode "there must be an index i, 0 <= i <= ary.size so that:

the block returns false for any element whose index is less than i; and
the block returns true for any element whose index is greater than or equal to i.

This method returns the i-th element. If i is equal to ary.size, it returns nil."
Examining your code
Now lets examine your statement, modified slightly:
arr = [1, 2, 3]
arr.bsearch { |el| el < 2 } #=> nil

We wish to find an index 0, 1 or 2 that satisfies the requirements imposed by the use of bsearch.
Suppose the index of interest were 0. As there are no indices less than zero, we test whether  arr[1] < 2 and arr[2] < 2 (2 < 2 and 3 < 2) are both true. In fact both are false. The index 0 is therefore removed from consideration.
Now suppose the index referred to in the doc were 1. We require that arr[0] < 2  be false, but it is true. So we can rule out index 1.
For the index to equal 2 to we require both arr[0] < 2 and arr[1] < 2 to be false but in fact both are true.
As there is no index that satisfies the requirement for using besearch nil is returned.
Correcting your code
It is evident that, for arr = [1, 2, 3], the expression must be written as follows.
arr.bsearch { |el| el >= 2 }      #=> 2
arr.bsearch { |el| el > 2  }      #=> 3
arr.bsearch { |el| el > 0  }      #=> 1
arr.bsearch { |el| el > 3  }      #=> nil

Other examples
Here are some more examples where the array contains integers.
ary = [2, 4, 6]

ary.bsearch { |el| el > -99 }     #=> 2
ary.bsearch { |el| el > 1 }       #=> 2
ary.bsearch { |el| el > 2 }       #=> 4
ary.bsearch { |el| el >= 2 }      #=> 2
ary.bsearch { |el| el >= 6 }      #=> 6
ary.bsearch { |el| el > 6 }       #=> nil

The array can be non-increasing
Note that the array need not be non-deceasing, only monotone, which means non-deceasing or non-increasing. Here is an example where the array is non-increasing (it is in fact strictly decreasing). The block calculation must of course be adjusting accordingly.
ary = [6, 4, 2]

ary.bsearch { |el| el <= 7 }    #=> 6
ary.bsearch { |el| el <= 99}    #=> 6
ary.bsearch { |el| el < 5 }     #=> 4
ary.bsearch { |el| el <= 4 }    #=> 4
ary.bsearch { |el| el < 4 }     #=> 2
ary.bsearch { |el| el <= 2 }    #=> 2
ary.bsearch { |el| el < 2 }     #=> nil  
ary.bsearch { |el| el <= 1 }    #=> nil

The array may contain non-numeric values
The only requirement is that pairs of elements can be compared with the spaceship operator, <=>. a <=> b returns -1 if a < b, returns 0 if a == b and returns 1 if a > b.
In the case of strings, for example, String#<=> is used by bsearch. Here are some examples.
ary = ['brush', 'keep', 'task']

ary.bsearch { |s| s >= 'hi' }     #=> "keep"
ary.bsearch { |s| s >= 'align' }  #=> "brush"
ary.bsearch { |s| s >= 'mama' }   #=> "task"
ary.bsearch { |s| s >= 'tar' }    #=> "task"
ary.bsearch { |s| s >= 'tax' }    #=> "nil"


Binary-search works on the basis of the following assumption

All false evaluations precede all true evaluations.

In other words, the evaluation result has to be in a form of either of the following for bsearch to return a non-nil, correct value:
 [true, (true, (true, ...))]
 [false, (false, (false, ...)), true, (true, (true, ...))]

Ruby's Array#bsearch is no exception (Note: the example above directly applies to the "find-minimum mode"; see Reference).
Your example violates the assumption, and this is why bsearch returns nil:
(arr=[1, 2]).map{ |el| el < 2 }
  # => [true, false]

where a false follows a true.
More detail
For detail, see the current definitive reference (Ruby-3.3.0).
The article "Effective Use of Array#bsearch" as the "Tip of the Week" in Ruby weekly #546 written by Jemma Issroff (their own archive) summarises the key point. The former says:

self should be sorted, but this is not checked.

and the latter basically reiterates it. The word of caution is, however, that the necessary way of sorting depends on your binary-search condition and what you want as a result. So, it usually does not agree with the default sorting Array#sort.
For example, consider the case with the following unsorted array:
[2, 1, 6, 5].bsearch { |el| el > 3 }
  # => 6

If "6" is your desired result (that is, the first occurrence where the condition is met), then this is fine. But if you expect the return value to be "5", then you need sort the Array as such before bsearch.
(And if you use bsearch in the find-any mode (see Reference), giving an unsorted Array to bsearch does not make sense.)

There is good explanation at https://jemma.dev/blog/array-bsearch
and for your case there can be 2 solutions
arr = [2, 1]
arr.bsearch { |el| el < 2 }

or
arr = [1, 2]
arr.bsearch { |el| el <=> 2 }

Looks like in the future I'll prefer to use simple find method

in the second example bsearch returns 2, but I need to find smaller number then 2 only
